# Android implicit Intent chooser to display Activities that are capable of viewing URLs

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to create a chooser intent to display activities that are capable of viewing  URL's. The first activity should be the Web Browser and the second activity should be a custom created activity I created call "MyBrowser".

When I run the code, no activities match my Intent. Here's how I'm calling the Implicit Intent:

```
Intent baseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse(URL));
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(baseIntent, CHOOSER_TEXT);
if (baseIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
}
```

Here is my intent-filter for my custom Browser Activity:

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: try adding a `mimeType` to your `<data />` tag http://blog.blundell-apps.com/add-your-app-to-the-android-menu/

Comment: For viewing you should use ACTION_VIEW, not ACTION_SEND

Comment: Hi, ACTION_VIEW opens the web browser but doesn't let me choose an app to handle the URL.

Comment: You were right, It had to be ACTION_VIEW. Found that I didn't register the BrowserApp correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` not `Intent.ACTION_SEND` to browse web pages.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW

Comment: ACTION_VIEW directly opens the web browser, it doesn't let me choose another app to handle the URL.

Comment: When you have two browsers installed what happens.

Comment: You were right, It had to be ACTION_VIEW. Found that I didn't register the BrowserApp correctly.